# Slow query time using group by with order by together

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query where I need to order results by a column. It works very fast (2.8 ms) if I order by id. But if I try to order by any other column (even indexed) the query execution time goes up high (800 ms). I can see in the EXPLAIN that ordering by id is using Index Scan and if I order by reg_date it does Seq Scan.

Here are my indexes. I also re-indexed the table.

```
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     indexname      |                                indexdef                                |
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| pk_users           | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX pk_users ON public.users USING btree (id)          |
| idx_users_reg_date | CREATE INDEX idx_users_end_date ON public.users USING btree (reg_date) |
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If I order by id then execution time is **2.601 ms**

```
select
    users.id,
    users.full_name,
    sum(user_comments.badges) as badges,
    count(user_comments) as comment_count
from
    users
left join user_comments
        on users.id = user_comments.user_id
group by users.id
order by users.id
limit 10
```

But if I order by users.reg_date column (which has an index) it is around **818.336 ms**

```
select
    users.id,
    users.full_name,
    sum(user_comments.badges) as badges,
    count(user_comments) as comment_count
from
    users
left join user_comments
        on users.id = user_comments.user_id
group by users.id
order by users.reg_date
limit 10;
```

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=73954.85..73954.88 rows=10 width=328) (actual time=614.913..614.914 rows=10 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=9 read=25307, temp read=6671 written=6671
  ->  Sort  (cost=73954.85..74216.20 rows=104539 width=328) (actual time=614.912..614.912 rows=10 loops=1)
        Sort Key: users.reg_date
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
        Buffers: shared hit=9 read=25307, temp read=6671 written=6671
        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=67941.35..71695.80 rows=104539 width=328) (actual time=432.031..598.345 rows=104539 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=6 read=25307, temp read=6671 written=6671
              ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=67941.35..69866.37 rows=104539 width=328) (actual time=432.019..535.760 rows=161688 loops=1)
                    Merge Cond: (users.id = user_comments.user_id)
                    Buffers: shared hit=6 read=25307, temp read=6671 written=6671
                    ->  Sort  (cost=33360.14..33621.49 rows=104539 width=8) (actual time=267.480..292.054 rows=104539 loops=1)
                          Sort Key: users.id
                          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1408kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=4 read=22164, temp read=181 written=181
                          ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..23213.39 rows=104539 width=8) (actual time=0.012..202.277 rows=104539 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=4 read=22164
                    ->  Materialize  (cost=34581.21..34981.87 rows=80133 width=324) (actual time=164.533..205.544 rows=80155 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=2 read=3143, temp read=6490 written=6490
                          ->  Sort  (cost=34581.21..34781.54 rows=80133 width=324) (actual time=164.525..193.679 rows=80155 loops=1)
                                Sort Key: user_comments.user_id
                                Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 24048kB
                                Buffers: shared hit=2 read=3143, temp read=6490 written=6490
                                ->  Seq Scan on user_comments  (cost=0.00..3946.33 rows=80133 width=324) (actual time=0.028..48.802 rows=80155 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=2 read=3143
Total runtime: 619.567 ms
```

Comment: Here it is https://explain.depesz.com/s/AijA

Comment: Oh, didn't know about that. Here is it - https://explain.depesz.com/s/Pvmt

Comment: You have two sorts that are done on disk which obviously is quite slow. You can avoid them by increasing the value for `work_mem`, e.g. `set work_mem='64MB';`

Comment: Try composite index `create index someindex ON users  (id, reg_date)`

Comment: Does it work better if you make the limit query a sub query e.g. `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT id, full_name FROM users ORDER BY reg_date LIMIT 10) u LEFT JOIN comments ...`

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in one of the comments there are sorts on disk, "Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 24048kB".

This should be avoided if possible, so if you have enough memory it is possible to increase work_mem.  Default value of "4MB" is rather small.

Remember it is possible to use up the systems memory if you have set work_mem large and has a lot of queries doing work at the same time.

To see temp file usage in the logfile you should also set "log_temp_files = 0"

Answer (score 0):

Is this improved with a lateral join?

```
select u.id, u.full_name,
       uc.badges, uc.comment_count
from users u left join lateral
     (select sum(uc.badges) as badges, count(*) as comment_count
      from user_comments uc
      where u.id = uc.user_id
     ) uc
order by u.reg_date
limit 10
```

Answer (score -1):

- First of all. Why the table 'user_itens' appear on your EXPLAIN? Are you using any view in this query?
- When you use the same key on GROUP BY and ORDER BY, and your key is UNIQUE, it makes Postgres use a better plan of course.
- Try to use a higher value for WORK_MEM in this session and try again (use the comand SET work_mem = 64MB or other value like that). Then run your query several times.